# Loading Worker from worker.js failed beacuse of disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)

Tags: javascript, mime-types, web-worker

I am trying to implement a simple **Web Worker**.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

The following is my **index.html** snippet :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  
        <title>Worker</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta content="X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/uikit.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
        
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    </head>
```

The follwing is my **index.js** **(Main javascript file)** :

```
var liveWorker;

function spawnLiveWorker()
{
    console.log("inside spawnLiveWorker()");
    if (typeof(Worker) !== "undefined")
    {
        if (typeof(liveWorker) == "undefined")
        {
            liveWorker = new Worker('worker.js');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        console.error("Sorry, your browser does not support Web Workers...");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("document ready");
    spawnLiveWorker();
});
```

The following is my **worker.js** :

```
var curURL = "http://172.30.206.80:8080/dp1_30";
var curAttrib = "2435";

function updateLiveDataWorker()
{
    console.log("inside updateLiveDataWorker()  in worker");
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
        {
            console.log("response type in updateLiveDataWorker = ",typeof this.response);
            console.log("response in updateLiveDataWorker = ",this.response);
            //console.log("")
            postMessage(this.response)
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("error");
        }
    }

    xhr.open("GET", "/api/device/getTimeSeriesDataForLastUpdatedDay");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJha3NoYXQuc3JpdmFzdGF2YUBtZGx6LmNvbSIsImV4cCI6MTYzNzU3ODg2OSwiaWF0IjoxNjM3NTYwODY5fQ.dUTJ7hm5xnJhBubDKB2F7-Ob2S83hlYmygrhVDFyuWQSmCWJ31vY_laksE0iP0nbyU2Pz2p578mjibCB3PIRUA");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("attributeId", curAttrib);

    xhr.send();
}

function startUpdatingLiveDataWorker()
{
    console.log("inside startUpdatingLiveDataWorker() in worker");
    setInterval(updateLiveDataWorker,30000);
}

updateLiveDataWorker();

startUpdatingLiveDataWorker();
```

However, I am getting this error :

```
GEThttp://172.30.206.80/worker/worker.js
[HTTP/1.1 404  1ms]

Loading Worker from “http://172.30.206.80/worker/worker.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
```

I have tried adding the following line as **meta tag** in **index.html** :

following instructions from the following page :
[X-Content-Type-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options)

Comment: `[HTTP/1.1 404  1ms]` this means that what got loaded was the 404 Not Found error page, not your worker script. The URL you passed to your Worker() constructor was incorrect.

Comment: Thanks. You were right. It should have been 'js/worker.js' and not 'worker.js' . I had assumed since the main script 'index.js' is in the same directory as the 'worker.js', so it should be able to load the page. But apparently it turns out we need to use the path relative to the root directory of the webapp. Now working. Thanks again for pointing out

Comment: The URL will be relative to the document's `.baseURI`, which can be either the url in the address bar, or if you have a <base> element, this <base> element's `href` value.

Comment: the worker.js script is a stateless script and has to implemented as the interface dictates. take a look https://github.com/mdn/simple-web-worker 
the error is indeed coused by 404 which is has an html's headers and your script expects javascript headers